# How to use dbGetQuery in tryCatch with PostgreSQL?

Tags: r, postgresql

I to try to use `tryCatch` querying my PostgreSQL database from R. 
Basically the query works, but I can't manage to catch errors and react to them. Here's an example

```
insert_rows <- function(dframe,con){

out <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(dframe)){
query <- .... some insert statement
tryCatch({dbGetQuery(con,query)},error=function(e) print("caught"))
}

}
```

When I create an error e.g. by entering duplicate records to unique PKs, I do see a PostgreSQL error and warning, but it's the standard printout from `RPostgreSQL`. I've used `tryCatch` in other contexts and it always worked this way. I have used `dbGetQuery` alot but I can't make them work together. Also, putting tryCatch into the out list did help much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dbSendQuery` for sending insert statements. The tryCatch will catch the exception in this case:

```
tryCatch({
  dbSendQuery(con, "insert into wrongtable values(1, 2, 3)")
},
error = function(e) print(e)
)
```

For using dbGetQuery (I don't know why it fails) there is a workaround -
call `postgresqlExecStatement` and `postgresqlFetch` instead of `dbGetQuery`:

```
tryCatch({
  res <- postgresqlExecStatement(con, "select * from thereisnotablewiththisname")
  postgresqlFetch(res)
},
error = function(e) print(e),
warning = function(w) print(w)
)
```

Comment: `dbSendquery`  works indeed. Don't know why I never considered it. Still though it would be interesting to understand why `dbGetQuery` fails in that matter.

Comment: @MattBannert I was fighting this issue a while back.  It is inherent in how the non-R code backing RPostgreSQL was written (I think C/C++, it has been awhile since I looked at it).  It emits the error to console without raising an error in R.

Comment: This is very usefull, I have also the same problem with sqldf, which I cannot surround with trycatch statements